# Python Class no output from print statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am learning Python from a book and reached classes. As I created my first program using classes, the program returns no output but just exits with code 0.

```
class Restaurant():

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print("\nThe restaurant is : " + self.restaurant_name)
        print('\nThe cuisine offered is : '+ self.cuisine_type)

    def open_restaurant():
        print('\n\nThe restaurant is open! ')

rest_1 = Restaurant("Good", 'Indian')
rest_1.describe_restaurant()
print("Hello")
```

I included the print("Hello") just to check the output comes or not but there is nothing. I guess I seriously messed something which might even be a pretty silly one. Help me out on this one!

Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://ideone.com/H9XY7x

Comment: Works for me as well.

Comment: whats is your IDE?

Comment: open_restaurant will take self as argument or make it static.

Comment: your code is working well...

Comment: Your code looks fine. Could you show us how you're running your code? (via an IDE, command line etc)

Comment: @eyllanesc PyCharm and Geany text editor. Tried both

Comment: @UnholySheep That's strange.

Comment: @prithajnath I ran via PyCharm and even the Geany text editor after installing Python in my PC (as suggested in the Book) btw, the book is 'Python Crash Course'.

Comment: @ramakrishnareddy you ran it via?(IDE or editor)

Comment: @K.Gupta i used jupyter notebook .